# How to edit firefox theme

Tags: firefox, themes

I want to edit existing theme, but I'm unable to locate `.css` files corresponding to themes I installed.
I've looked in `$HOME/.mozilla/firefox`, but found nothing relevant.
I found some old questions on this topic, but none of them were up to date (I mean files were not there).

I installed the theme from mozilla's addons page, using firefox 102 on linux.

Answer (score 0):

I found this on Mozilla Support:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/940165

Not sure how much this helps, but its something.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I've found that before. I want to locate archive file mentioned there on my computer. I know how to handle archives...